# Android Java не подключается к серверу

Tags: java, android, веб-сервер

Код:

```
<!-- language: java -->
package ru.network;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;


import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ProfileAct extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private static String LOGIN_URL = "http://nw.pe.hu/******.php?id=";
    static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
     }
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.profile);
        Log.d("request user!", LOGIN_URL + getIntent().getStringExtra("ID"));
        try{
            HttpURLConnection conn;
            URL url = new URL(LOGIN_URL + getIntent().getStringExtra("ID"));

            // *** Определяем переменную conn ***
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                Log.d("1", "TRUE");
                conn.setReadTimeout(5000 /* milliseconds */);
                Log.d("2", "TRUE");
                conn.setConnectTimeout(5000 /* milliseconds */);
                Log.d("3", "TRUE");
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                Log.d("4", "TRUE");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                Log.d("5", "TRUE");
                // *** Запускаем соединение с сервером ***
                conn.connect();
                Log.d("CONN", "TRUE");

            // *** Определяем переменную stream, чтобы в будущем влезть в поток ***
                InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
                Log.d("7", "TRUE");
            // *** И определяем переменную data в которую заносим все, что нам вернул сервер в виде строки ***
                String data = convertStreamToString(stream);
                Log.d("8", "TRUE");
            // *** Выводим в logcat, что нам вернул сервер ***
                Log.d("DATA >> ",data);

            }
            catch(MalformedURLException e)  {
                Log.d("URL", "Cant new URL 228  >8-(");
            } 
            catch (IOException e)  {
                Log.d("CONNECTION", "NO CONNECTION!! >8-(");
            }

        // getting product details by making HTTP request
    }
}
```

Comment: И что, собственно, с этим кодом делать?  Какую ошибку выдает? Где?

Comment: Выходит черный экран. В LogCat ничего не пишет. TryCatch не помогает. Postman - REST Client выдает нормальный ответ

Comment: Как выглядит `profile.xml`?  Вы уверены, что он правильно его загружает?

Comment: Точнее с LogCat пишет request user!  http://nw.pe.hu/******.php?id=1;     1 TRUE ...  5 TRUE

Comment: profile.xml нормально грузит, проверял без кода подключения

Comment: Попробуйте вместе обоих `catch(...)` поставить `catch(Throwable e) { Log.e("CONNECTION", e.toString(), e); }` - и посмотрите, что он напишет в logcat.

Comment: http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=f794d30be8ba6527b49e53dc00d55dc0

Comment: http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=aeb16ad1eaebb4911a48d20d9b7fea26

Comment: Но теперь еще выводит profile.xml

Comment: А, ну так все понятно.  В первой картинке первая строчка все объясняет: `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Андроид не разрешает устанавливать сетевые соединения на главном UI thread - нужно использовать другой thread, например AsyncTask.

Comment: @Aleks G,То есть как изменить код?

Comment: Почитайте документацию об AsyncTask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка (из комментариев):

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Андроид не разрешает устанавливать сетевые соединения на главном UI thread - нужно использовать другой thread, например [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Вот [еще немного информации по теме](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html).